# Problem in JSF2 with client-side state saving and serialization

Tags: jsf, client-side, state, jsf-2, save

I have a problem in JSF2 with client side state saving and serialization. I have created a page with a full description and a small class diagram: http://tinyurl.com/jsf2serial.  For the client-side state saving I have to implement `Serializable`  at the classes `Search`, `BackingBean` and `Connection`. The exception that was thrown is:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1338)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1146)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:293)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:167)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:155)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:397)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Maybe this is a problem of my design, because I am new in developing Java webapps.

Answer (score 1):

The exception basically tells that you cannot (and should not) not store `HttpClient` in `HttpSession`. Apparently you've assigned it as a property of some session scoped bean. You should not do that. Either declare it `transient` or keep it threadlocal (i.e. only declare and use it in local method block, so that you can get rid of the property). The latter approach has my recommendation since `HttpClient` maintains some internal state which might make your application to break when it all get deserialized. If you'd like to have a long-living instance of it because recreating it is expensive, then I recommend to store it in an application scoped bean instead.

Comment: thanks, i try transient... but if you take a look at the class diagram you see, that the connection is application scoped... and the bean with the properties are view scoped...

Comment: I didn't have a close look to the diagram, actually the whole image didn't show up. But storing the connection in the application scope is a bad idea. You can't expect that the connection will live as long as your application lives. It will timeout sooner or later and your application may break.

Comment: hm... i like to store in the connection in applecation scope... all user should use the same connection and on application startup the connection should be started...

Comment: You may take it whatever you want. You've at least been warned :) External resources should always be acquired and closed in the shortest possible scope.

Comment: how do you handle this? i am new at the java web-dev world :/

Comment: Declare, acquire and close in a `try-finally` inside the method block where you need to access the resource. This is not specifically related to Java webdevelopment, but to programming in general.

Comment: @Bozho: yes, someone with old hurts who wanted more attention from me. Fortunately they are recently all (35 or so over 2 days) removed.